# Making Android Native Component for ReactNative fails with ViewGroupManager and FrameLayout

Tags: android, react-native

I want to make a Android Native UI Component for ReactNative. I referenced [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video), since I'm going to make a player component. Also I checked the ReactNative [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.72/native-components-android).

The following code is a simple java files that is render TextView.

When I run the following app, the `TextView` component, which is from the Android, now show up on the screen.

How can I show the component using `ViewGroupManager` and `FrameLayout`?

## Code

### MyPackage implements ReactPackage

```java
public class MyPackage implements ReactPackage {
  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
      new ReactTextViewManager(reactContext)
    );
  }

  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
          ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

    return modules;
  }
}
```

### ReactTextViewManager extends ViewGroupManager

I use `ViewGroupManager` because the react-native-video use it as the view manager.

```java
public class ReactTextViewManager extends ViewGroupManager<ReactTextView> {
  public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTTextView";
  private static final String TAG = "ReactTextViewManager";
  ReactApplicationContext mCallerContext;
  public ReactTextViewManager(ReactApplicationContext context) {
    mCallerContext = context;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public ReactTextView createViewInstance(@NonNull ThemedReactContext context) {
    return new ReactTextView(context);
  }

  @ReactProp(name = "text")
  public void setText(ReactTextView view, String text) {
    Log.i(TAG, "ReactProp: " + text);
    view.setText(text);
  }
}
```

### ReactTextView extends FrameLayout

I use `FrameLayout` because the react-native-video use it as the view.

```java
public class ReactTextView extends FrameLayout {
  private final TextView textView;

  public ReactTextView(ThemedReactContext context) {
    super(context);

    textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    addView(textView);
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    if (textView != null) {
      textView.setText(text);
    }
  }
}
```

### register and usage

#### MainApplication

```java
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        // ...
        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());

          packages.add(new MyPackage());

          return packages;
        }
        //...
}
```

#### ReactNative

```
import { HostComponent, requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

interface TextViewProps {
  text?: string;
}

export type VideoComponentType = HostComponent<TextViewProps>;

export default requireNativeComponent<TextViewProps>(
  'RCTTextView',
) as VideoComponentType;
```

and

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import TextView from './components/TextView';

function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Top</Text>
      <TextView text="Hello World" />
      <Text>Bottom</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#dedede',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fix it with style in the `TextView` component like

```
<TextView text="..." style={styles.textView} />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```